# How to solve "exception firing resume/pause event from native" Cordova Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

My android phonegap/cordova application keeps getting this message:

***"exception firing resume/pause event from native"***

It appears in my logcat

> I/chromium(22500): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "exception
>   firing pause event from native", source:
>   file:///android_asset/www/login_page.html (1)

and these are the first 4 lines of **login_page.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

I am using cordova 3.5 and JQueryMobile.
Though my application is still working, what is the reason/meaning of this exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure you added the cordova.js to your scripts in your login_page.html?

When the android app receives a 'pause' event, the following code is issues:

```
this.loadUrl("javascript:try{cordova.fireDocumentEvent('pause');}catch(e){console.log('exception firing pause event from native');};");
```

So, it is probably related to the absence of variable *cordova* in the context. Adding cordova.js will put variable cordova in the context and *cordova.fireDocumentEvent* will be there, avoiding the exception.

Comment: Hi @mvermand, I'm having the same exceptions, the difference is that my app runs fine in Ripple and only a black screen appears on the Android Emulator. I'm using Ionic template for Visual Studio. I've tried to add the cordova.js manually (even though VS generates it automatically on build) but it doesn't solve the issue anyway. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @RafaelMerlin, I'm not familiar with Ripple and have only limited experience with android emulators. I guess you'll need to try to get to the debug info. Maybe you can try to follow this: http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/testing.html

Comment: I am having this issue without Ripple. 

Does this answer fix the problem?

Comment: @tokam my answer was not specific to Ripple, so yes, it should fix the problem.